# OpenGL FBO - White pixels appear transparent

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, alphablending, fbo

I'm making a 2D game using OpenGL. I recently tried implementing Framebuffer-objects, and I am having some problems regarding blending.

I'm creating an FBO (using GL_RGBA as format).
When I render to the FBO, I first clear it to fully transparent black, and disable GL_BLEND. I then draw my textures and then I enable GL_BLEND again.
When I'm drawing the FBO-texture, I use GL_SRC_ALPHA and GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA as source and destination pixels respectively, as the blending-function. I am rendering it as a textured quad.
This does not work properly, as white pixels appear transparent. I have tried experimenting with different blend-function values, but all that I have tried have had issues. I do not fully understand how blending works, so it's hard for me to wrap my head around this. Maybe I'm missing something obvious here?

Here's an image of how it looks right now. There is supposed to be a glow around the button when it is being highlighted, but instead the pixels around it appear transparent: http://i.snag.gy/RnV4s.jpg

You can also see two boxes of text in the image. The top one is drawn normally, without an FBO. The textures are also rendered normally without an FBO, so I know that the problem lies within my framebuffer-code somewhere.

I have pasted my "RenderTarget" class to pastebin (I'm used to calling it a rendertarget instead of FBO): http://pastebin.com/dBXgjrUX

This is how I use it:

```
RT->Begin();
// draw stuff
RT->End();
RT->Draw();
```

Can someone help me? Let me know if you need any more info about my issue.

Edit:
Here are the properties of OpenGL that I set on startup:

```
// Initialize shaders
shaderManager.InitializeStockShaders();

// Set some OpenGL properties
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.0f);

// Enables/disables
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDisable(GL_DITHER);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
```

Comment: If you clear to transparent black instead, do the black pixels disappear instead of the white ones?  I'm wondering if the driver in render to FBO is optimizing out the writes to the pixels that are already white.

Comment: Whoops! I actually clear to transparent black (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0). Sorry about that. I've edited the question. I tried clearing to white though, and that gives the same results.

Answer (score 2):

I'ts a bit difficult to tell what your problem is exactly, because you didn't provide source code. Alas, I see several potential troublemakers:

First you told that you want to draw a glow around the button. I presume, that all the buttons are drawn into the FBO, merging them into a UI overlay. Glow sounds to me, like you want to blend something, so you probably also want to have blending enabled, drawing to the FBO.

Next be aware of depth buffer issues. Blending and Depth Buffering have peculiar interactions. In your case I suggest disabling depth testing and depth writes to the FBO (or not using a depth buffer attachment to the FBO at all). Draw the glowing button last, so that it won't block the other buttons from being drawn. Also you must make sure, that your glow comes out with a nonzero alpha value, otherwise it will blend transparent. This is something you control in your shaders, or texture environment (depending on what you use).

---

#### Update 1:

Your FBO class doesn't propperly ensure, that textures attached to a bound framebuffer must not be bound themself. It's easy to fix though, by moving attachment code into bind, where the textures are also unbound apropriately. See my edited pastebin http://pastebin.com/1uVT7VkR (I probably missed a few things).

Comment: The depth-testing is disabled (GL_DEPTH_TEST) at the start of the application. The glow is actually being drawn last, although it is still a part of the framebuffer. I actually have the project up on github, but I don't want to post the link publicly. Check out the pastebin link in the question if you want to see my RenderTarget.cpp class, though. That's where I handle all the FBO-stuff.

Comment: That's quite nice, datenwolf. I didn't realize this. I have now implemented your changes, and it runs fine. However, this sadly did not seem to fix my alpha-transparency issue.

Comment: I have made an update to it so that one can flip through every possible combination of blending. No combination yields satisfactory results. I've got the source on github if anyone wants to help: https://github.com/Landeplage/Amigo